# subset and transpose python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, subset, transpose

I have an array:

```
[['a','1'.'2','3','4'],['b','5','6','7','8'],['c','9','10','11','12'],['d','13','14','15','16']]
```

I want to subset this and transpose. For transpose it i tried zip function but it outputs array which when i write into a csv file doesn't have the format as tab delimited.

output desired:

```
a   b
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
c   d
9   13
10   14
11   15
12   16
```

Since i am not able to make tab here i am leaving three spaces in the output.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do to your data structure. The term "subset" has no connection to what you're doing; I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Try : `zip(array[0],array[1])` and `zip(array[1],array[2])`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The result is a tuple. Can i get it as a matrix as well??

Comment: @Vignesh http://ideone.com/BX9NAo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the output that looks like what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['a','1','2','3','4'],
              ['b','5','6','7','8'],
              ['c','9','10','11','12'],
              ['d','13','14','15','16']])

new_a = np.hstack((a[:2,], a[2:])).T
```

Result:

```
>>> new_a
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['1', '5'],
       ['2', '6'],
       ['3', '7'],
       ['4', '8'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['9', '13'],
       ['10', '14'],
       ['11', '15'],
       ['12', '16']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```